# What weapons were manufactured in India by the British forces which were used during world wars?

Tags: war, british-empire, india

Recently I came across references to a weapon called [the Bangalore Torpedo](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bangalore_torpedo), which was used in the world wars. These weapons were made in India by the British Indian Army.
I also happened to see references to these weapons in the movie *Saving Private Ryan*.

My question is:

> Were there any more weapons used in the
>   world wars, that were made in India, and were British colonies like
>   India used for the manufacture of weapons for British Army ?

Comment: Bangalore Torpedo was designed in Bangalore, according to [wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bangalore_torpedo), but it doesn't talk about manufacturing.

Comment: so are you suggesting that they were not manufactured in India?

Comment: well looks like some things are still made in britain:http://www.mondial-defence.com/2011/Products/Bangalore_4_Tube.html

Comment: @kartshan Due to logistics in most industries (including military production), manufacturing and research/development might not be co-located. It's more probable that less specialized equipment was manufactured in India (like guns etc.) for the military's consumption.

Comment: I found this but it doesn't go into the depth of detail you want: http://ww2total.com/WW2/History/Production/Anglo-Americans/British-production.htm

Answer (score 7):

The British had gun manufacturing set up in India, see [Ordnance Factories Board on wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ordnance_Factories_Board#History).

In 1940, to combat the growing threat of Japan, a military aircraft manufacturing  facility was set up in Bangalore. See [Hindustan Aeronautics Limited](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hindustan_Aeronautics_Limited#History).

Can't find any mention of naval or artillery production, but it's possible they were setup by the British.

Comment: I was told that HAL led to present-day hi-tech industries in Bangalore. If its true, British plan for weapons manufacturing led to today's high-tech scene in India!